# Как посчитать количество и вывести сумму(класс корзины + куки)?

Tags: php, html, cookie, pdo

Недавно перешел на ооп и делаю корзину для сайта. Нашел корзину тут - [Корзина](https://devionity.com/ru/courses/php-shopping-cart/adding-ajax)

**С куками еще не сильно знаком и в целом с ООП. Но хочется разобраться.**

Есть класс Cart, в котором существуют 2 метода, отвечающих за товары

```
public function getItems($for_sql = false)
{
    if ($for_sql) {
        return implode(',', $this->items);
    }

    return $this->items;
}

public function addItem($id)
{
    $id = (int)$id;

    $key = array_search($id, $this->items);

    if (!in_array($id, $this->items)) {
        array_push($this->items, $id);
    }
     Cookie::set('items', serialize($this->items));
}
```

А в файле cart.php я вывожу таким способом:

```
echo "My cart: <br>";
foreach ($items as $items) {
    echo "<b>{$items['name']}</b> | Количество " .count($items['id']). " | <a href='cart.php?action=delete&id={$items['id']}'>Удалить из корзины</a><br>";
```

}

Пытался вывести количество повторных id через count, но также безуспешно. Поэтому прошу помощи
Как сделать следующее:

1. Как сложить количество товара, если этот товар уже добавлен к корзину?
   На данный момент только 1 раз товар добавляется, а дальше количество этого товара не добавляется( + 1 к количеству)
2. Как вывести общую сумму, используя этот класс корзины?

Пытался добавить в метод addItem($id) функцию array_key_exists(), но безуспешно. Количество не складывается.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Comment: Используйте класс Cart, там есть метод getProducts, который вероятно выдаст все продукты добавленные в корзину. Далее, сумму можете посчитать в цикле.

Comment: Я использую класс Cart. Я хотел проверить наличие id в массиве через array_key_exists в методе
    public function addItem($id)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;

        $key = array_search($id, $this->items);

        if (!in_array($id, $this->items)) {
            array_push($this->items, $id);
        }
         Cookie::set('items', serialize($this->items));
    }

Или это неверно?